# help me prove reflexivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

[image]

So given this problem, im trying to prove for part a) that $A\tau B$ is reflexive

so far this is what ive come up with:

for $A,B \in \mathcal P(X)$ if $A \tau B$ , then $A=B$.

since $A=B$, $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall b \in B$, $a=a$ and $b=b$

so $A\tau B$ is reflexive.

my answer is sort of an educated guess so i dont think its entirely correct. its always tempting to just ask for someone to correct me but I like discrete math and I want to be good at it so rather then giving me a quick fix, can someone guide me through this?

-Thanks

Comment: Please note: If we take $X=\{1,2,3\}$, we get $\{1,2\}\tau \{3\}$, but clearly $\{1,2\}\neq\{3\}$. So the assertion that $A\tau B \Rightarrow A=B$ is wrong.

Comment: How are you defining the sum of an infinite subset of integers?

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that $\tau$ is reflexive means that $\bigl(\forall A\in\mathcal{P}(X)\bigr):A\tau A$. This means that the sum of the elements of $A$ is equal to the number of elements of $A$, which is trivially true.

Comment: Is {0} equivalent to Z?  Don't they have the same sum?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I don't know what the author meant by sum of the elements in $A$ in some cases (such has when $A=\mathbb{Z}$), but what I wrote reamins valid.

Comment: both A and B are finite sets which exists in the powerset of X and X is a subset of the set of integers so the sum of all the elements in A means {$a_1 + a_2 +... +a_n$} for all $a\in A$

Comment: @kr1s How do you know they're finite?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i thought because X was a subset of the set of integers and A was a subset of the powerset but i just re-thought that and realised it doesnt imply they are finite at all

Comment: @kr1s Was my answer helpful?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so based on your answer, im thinking i will find my proof for this by going and looking at the definition of reflexivity on a set more thoroughly

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos is this an answer that you posted or a hint to help me find the answer?

Comment: @kr1s It is an answer to the problem of proving that $\tau$ is reflexive.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for your answer. So is the statement 'trivially true' because the two sets A and A are both the same set hence the have equal properties?

Comment: @kr1s Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

So $\tau$ is defined as $\{(A,B) \in \mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(X): \sum_{n \in A} n = \sum_{n \in B} n\}$.

Reflexive means that for any $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ we have $(A,A) \in \tau$.
This holds iff $\sum_{n \in A} n = \sum_{n \in A} n$ which is trivially true.

Symmetry is also trivial: if $A$ has the same sum as $B$, then $B$ has the same sum as $A$. Transitivity is similarly trivial.

$\emptyset$ has sum $0$, as does $\{0\}$, so they form one class.

For sum $1$, we just have the elements $\{1\}, \{0,1\}$.

For sum $2$, we have the class $\{2\}, \{0,2\}$.

Similarly $\{3\}, \{0,3\}, \{1,2\}, \{0,1,2\}$ form one class.

etc.

Comment: i see, so it is reflexive because, using the definition of power sets, ($A,A$) has to be in $\mathcal P (x)$ and also in the cartesian product of $\mathcal P(x)$ and $(A,A)$ implies $A\tau A$, am i getting somewhere with my understanding?

Comment: also would i be correct for transitivity saying: for a set $C \in \tau$ if $\sum n \in A^n$=$\sum n \in B^n$ then $\sum n \in A^n$ = $\sum n \in C^n$ ?

Comment: @kr1s you’re making no sense. You seem to be confused about what a relation on a set $Y$ actually *is*

Comment: $A\tau B$ means the same as $(A, B)\in\tau$.

Comment: yes im very confused about it all